# Find if the series converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find if the series converges or diverges, $a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+\ln (n)}$.  Comparing it with another series $b_n=\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$. Dividing both the series and taking limits, we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{1+\ln(n)}$.  Since it is the $\infty/\infty$ form, applying H'opitals rule, we get, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1/n}{1/n}=1$.  Now, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{ln(n)}=0, \Rightarrow b_n$  converges $\Rightarrow a_n$ converges.  But the answer is, Comparing it with $\frac{1}{n}$(divergent harmonic series) we get,$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{1+\ln(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n=\infty \Rightarrow a_n $  diverges, what is wrong with my comparison?

Comment: There's something confusing here: you define $a_n$ as a quantity that doesn't depend on $n$. You probably meant that $a_n$ is the $n^{th}$ term of the series. And, for the limit comparison test (which I assume you're using), you need to know whether $\sum b_n$ converges or not.

Comment: In fact $\sum_{2}^\infty \frac{1}{\log n}$  diverges. You seem to be saying that if $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. This is not rue.

Comment: Proof that $\sum_2^\infty$ $1\over\log_bn$ diverges: $\log_bn < n$(at least for $n >$ some value) so $1\over\log_bn $$>$$1\over{n}$ and $\sum$$1\over{n}$ is divergent so $\sum$$1\over\log_bn$ is divergent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is when you say that: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} b_n = 0$$ implies that $\sum b_n$ is convergent. That doesn't hold in general.

Note further that  $n > \ln(n)$ so $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$. So by comparison $\sum \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ is divergent.

So as mentioned in the comment above, your comparison is fine, the conclusion is just that the series is divergent.